# Hatchback vs sedan snow performance

Tags: body, driving

I haven't owned a hatchback and was wondering, holding everything else equal, if they perform better in snow than sedans.

Comment: Define "performance in snow"

Comment: Imho, it could very well change the drivability of the car due to the reasons Anarach mentions, but if it is for the better or worse depends on a lot of things. AWD is best for traction of course, but for 2wd the variant with more weight on the drive wheels should be better at low speeds, deep snow, uphill etc. Regarding handling, a more neutral distribution is usually preferred as Juann says.

Comment: @Zaid, how does it handle snowy conditions, i.e. how close a 2WD gets to a 4WD in terms of handling

Comment: Not sure what 2WD vs 4WD has to do with sedan vs hatchback

Comment: how close a 2WD hatchback emulates a 4WD in handling features

Comment: Not much I would say... The traction provided by then engine weight Cannot offset the traction provided by a true 4WD system

Comment: That is true. 4wd is good to have in snow. It gives better traction and often makes recovering slides easier. That said, I drive rwd and have snow at least 6 months a year. That's no problem as long as you have good winter tires.

Comment: but it's annoying to have to change tires every 6 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real world difference between a sedan and a hatchback is the added trunk(weight) and in some cases a longer wheelbase in case of a sedan.(Not counting Looks obviously)

The above difference doesn't define the driveability of the vehicle on snow.

To drive on snow a AWD drive system with traction control and higher ground clearance is all that's needed no matter if its a sedan or a hatchback.

To support my above statement, take rallying for instance, the best performing cars are usually hatchbacks just because they weigh less than the sedan and have smaller turning radius allowing to pull tight corners. All of them have AWD systems.

In the real world, its difficult to find a AWD hatchback(economical ones) so you are limited to sedans mostly if you drive on snow only or mostly.

To answer your question: It does not matter which one you buy since the performance in snow is not dependant on the vehicle being a hatchback or a sedan.

Comment: AWD means next to nothing for traction if your tires are junk. Incidentally, a FWD will generally do just fine in the snow with proper snow tires. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfuE00qdhLA).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter. Everything else being equal, the car with the most neutral weight distribution would perform best in snow. I would even think that the car that has the bulk of its weight up front would be least inclined to skid or overstear. Usually, that would be a hatchback, but in these modern times most vehicle manufacturers build their cars with neutral weight distribution whether they're hatchbacks or sedans.

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on the specific vehicle and more so on the type of tyres fitted.

As a side note, my old Lancia Delta HF Integrale 16V rally car (a hatchback) was brilliant on the snow whilst my fathers Lexus IS200 (a saloon) was awful.

Comment: Lancia Delta from the late 1980s was such an awesome car...